# Changing cursor afects all above

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

The issue I ran into is the following:

- Changing the cursor of a control affects the cursor even if the cursor is above a different control, as long as those other controls are above the control that had the cursor changed. This persist until cursor is moved.

[An example.](https://streamable.com/m4d2ha)

Is there a way to prevent this behavior ?

The goal was to have my controls change cursor when the form is not focused, after a few different ways to do it I settled on a timer.

Comment: I have dont have your answer but did you try with a showdialog ? This will disable the first form while the 2nd is opened.

Comment: @UserNam3 I did not try, but Showdialog is not an option.

Comment: Remove the Timer (that's your problem, there's no *bug*), override `OnDeactivate()` and `OnActivated()` instead.

Comment: @Jimi I need the cursor changed under certain conditions while not focused, not permanently. I also tried that but it acted the same. Changing cursor causes it, not the timer.

Comment: *I need the cursor changed under certain conditions while not focused, not permanently*: that's exactly what I suggested. Set `pictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.No` in `OnDeactivate()` and `pictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Default` in `OnActivated()`. The problem IS the Timer (I can say it like this or I can say *the problem is the way you're using a Timer*).

Comment: @Jimi OnDe/Activate only triggers once, not periodically. It won't react to keys pressed when it's not focused. Regardless, this bug occurs even if it's triggered only once, timer is not the issue (it only exacerbates it). But what do you suggest other than the timer?

Comment: *The goal was to have my controls change cursor when the form is not focused*: is this the condition or is it not? If it is, then what I suggested causes the PictureBox control to change Cursor when the parent Form is deactivated and reset the default Cursor when it's activated. While the parent Form is not active, moving the Mouse Pointer over the PictureBox (and only over the PictureBox) will show a `Cursors.No`. No idea what *It won't react to keys pressed* means. If you have different *conditions* you didn't mention, then add these other conditions to the question.

Comment: @Jimi Cursor is supposed to be different while the key(s) are held, regardless of focus.